# SQLServerException when migrating SQL server from 2012 to 2016

Tags: java, sql-server

We have migrated the SQL server version from 2012 to 2016, after the migration our application is throwing SSL error.

> Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016  
>   Java Version: 1.7 
>  
>   JDBC Driver: mssql-jdbc 
>   Driver Version: 4.0

Here is the Log

```
2020-01-09 13:02:13.108 [main] [] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException:526 - springHikariCP - Exception during pool initialization.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1368) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1412) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1058) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:577) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:57) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341) ~[HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:193) ~[HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:428) [HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:499) [HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar:na]
```

Can I get some help in understanding what is wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/879 might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the driver version after upgrade from 4.0 to 6.0.1 it's working fine.